# How can I create a lightning attack similar to Agahnim's in Legend of Zelda: Link to the Past?

Tags: c++

I'm currently trying to [recreate this attack](https://youtu.be/5zGAlpM668Y?t=80), and I'm unsure of how it works.

[image: Animation showing the lightning effect]

It seems like the boss creates 4 lightning bolts which move downward at 45 degree/diagonal angles, changing direction every so often.

I'm building my game in [Zelda Classic](http://www.zeldaclassic.com/). I'd preferably like to know how to do this in C++, although I am fine with Java or anything C++/C-like.

Comment: What do you want to reproduce exactly? The visual effect? What have you tried? Do you work in 2d, 3d? What framework do you use? I'm asking because questions about "how did they do it" is off topic here, what you really want to ask is "how can I do it", but in it's current state, there is not really a starting point in your question for us to help you the best we could...

Comment: Oh, sorry. I've edited the question with details. I'm assuming by framework, you meant language, yes?

Comment: No; more like Unity/SFML/gml, do you use some sort of tiling features, ect. The right answer for you really depends on how your game is currently set up. The more information about how your game is programmed, the better the answer(s) you'll get :)

Comment: This is still off-topic, and we don't know what "2d enviroment" mea s exactky

Comment: Oh, by 2D environment, I meant top down, like in AlttP.

As for my framework, I've never used either of those, but what I'm using has it's own editor for the level design, and objects/like can be given special coding. The language I'm using is most similar to C++. It is possible to create variables (booleans, ints (although all integers/numberwise variables are treated as fixed, so float and int are identical, in that ints can also go into decimals)), loops (for loops, while loops, and do while loops), and arrays (only 1 dimensional, though). 

(continued)

Comment: Bitmaps are also supported (they work like a canvas, where you can draw to them, have them save between frames (the program uses frames as a measure of drawing: 60 frames per second, and a command (Waitframe();) advances to the next frame) and draw segments from them to the screen.

(continued)

Comment: As for functions/commands, there are a good amount of drawing commands. I believe the one most applicable here is line drawing, the function for it is

void Line(int layer, int x, int y, int x2, int y2, int color, float scale,
int rx, int ry, int rangle, int opacity);

Layer, scale, Rx, Ry, Rangle, and Opacity can be ignored. x/y are the location of the line starting point, and x2/y2 are the end point. Color corresponds to the palette, you can just ignore that too.

Comment: The full documentation for all the commands can be found here (hopefully not required)

http://pastebin.com/sq9G3UvK

Sorry if this isn't enough information, I can provide more if needed :(

Comment: @Dimentio You could've just linked to the main page of the engine...

Comment: http://www.zeldaclassic.com/

Comment: So, is this your question: "How could I create the lightning attack pattern as seen in this video? I'm using Zeldaclassic, so I can use the Line method, or any other method. I don't need the exact syntax I should use, pseudocode will be fine, I have issues figuring out the pattern of the lightning graphics. I know that if I use the 'line' method, I'll be able to do intersection tests to see if it touches the player; other methods will have to show how this can be achieved."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks to me like a [Random Walk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk) (image from Wikipedia):

[image: Random Walk graph example from Wikipedia]

1. Seed each lightning bolt with a start point (the orb in the enemy's hands)
2. Each step, the bolt's leading point moves down one unit, and with 50/50 probability moves either one unit left or one unit right, drawing a line between its previous & new positions.

   (You can choose the size of the units yourself, or measure them from the frames of the original game if you want pixel-for-pixel fidelity)
3. You can advance each bolt one step per frame, or loop through n steps if you want the bolt to advance more quickly.
4. Once the bolt reaches the bottom of the screen, it's complete.

You can store up all the positions it's raced through along the way in an array to do collision checks (it may suffice to skip between every nth point to simplify your checks), and to re-draw the bolts in varying colours on subsequent frames to get the strobing effect.

To wipe the bolts, you start drawing from further and further down the array on subsequent frames, leaving the top part of the bolt un-drawn, until it's completely hidden.

Comment: From the [second lightning attack in the video](https://youtu.be/5zGAlpM668Y?t=114), it seems that the lightning is a bit directed: it is a bit more toward the right-hand side of the screen, where link is situated at some point. Perhaps a bias should be added to the going left or right decision, based on the location of link when casting the spell.